# Oracle SQL - DATE greater than statement

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format

As the title says, I want to find a way to check which of my data sets are past 6 months from SYSDATE via query.

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
WHERE OrderDate <= '31 Dec 2014';
```

I've tried the following but it returns an error saying my date format is wrong. However, inserting the data I used that date format as requested/intended and had no issues.

> Error at Command Line : 10 Column : 25
>
> Blockquote
>
> Error report -
>
> SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>
> *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>
> *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: Are your date stored as `DATE` or as `VARCHAR` ?

Comment: 'DATE' stored as that, and I can't convert them using to_date

Answer (score 115):

As your query string is a literal, and assuming your dates are properly stored as `DATE` you should use [date literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ):

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
WHERE OrderDate <= DATE '2015-12-31'
```

If you want to use [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) (because, for example, your query value is not a literal), I suggest you to explicitly set the [NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options067.htm#OLADM408) parameter as you are using US abbreviated month names. That way, it won't break on some localized Oracle Installation:

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
WHERE OrderDate <= to_date('31 Dec 2014', 'DD MON YYYY',
                           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American');
```

Comment: Thank you, I stumbled on your answer and it gives me the right answer. However could you please explain why `WHERE created >= Convert(datetime,  '2014-04-01')` doesn't work? Says Syntax error.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey Convert is not related to datetime conversion, rather it is used for converting between character sets (Latin-1 to ASCII etc.)

Answer (score 41):

You need to convert the string to date using the `to_date()` function

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
WHERE OrderDate <= to_date('31-Dec-2014','DD-MON-YYYY');
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
WHERE OrderDate <= to_date('31 Dec 2014','DD MON YYYY');
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
WHERE OrderDate <= to_date('2014-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd');
```

This will work only if `OrderDate` is stored in `Date format`. If it is `Varchar` you should apply `to_date()` func on that column also like

```
 SELECT * FROM OrderArchive
    WHERE to_date(OrderDate,'yyyy-Mm-dd') <= to_date('2014-12-31','yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the To_Date() function to convert the string to date !
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php